# jQuery parent()

Tags: jquery, parent

**jQuery snippet:**

```
$(".sliders dt a").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".triggers a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).parent().next("dd").slideToggle("fast");
    return false
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="sliders">
    <div class="triggers">
       <a href="#" class="active">Hide all</a>
    </div>
    <dl>
        <dt>
            <a href="#">text</a>
        </dt>
        <dd>text</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Three `.parent()` is used, to catch `.triggers` block. **Is there any way to merge them?**

---

**jQuery 1.2.6. version is used, thats why `.closest()` solutions don't work.**

Comment: Can you update to include the parent element in your markup?

Comment: wtf? haha... did Nick change posters html?

Comment: @hunter - The poster did, I asked for Happy to clarify the question, you can always click the link beside "edited" at the bottom to see revision history and who edited what.

Comment: @hunter - That's why Nick is never wrong. He just updates all the questions to fit his answers!  :oP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) like this:

```
$(".sliders dt a").click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".sliders").find(".triggers a").removeClass("active");
    return false
});
```

This goes up to the `.sliders` div then back down to find the `.triggers a` beneath.

Comment: I think this is wrong since, from the jQuery documentation, it finds ancestors, but .triggers is a sibling of .sliders

Comment: @hunter - I'm not using `.triggers` for the selector in `.closest()`, this goes to the whatever that parent is then looks for `.triggers a` beneath.

Comment: I reformatted his code. It is clearer now that the elements in question are siblings. Your solution assumes that the shared parent only has one `.triggers` element.

Comment: @patrick - We think they're siblings...but seeing as it says "Hide All" there may be some repeated elements not included in the question :)

Comment: @Happy - Thanks :) Answer is updated with the correct selector.

Comment: @Nick Craver - Good point as usual. Ultimately we don't have enough code to divine the ultimate intent.

Comment: @Nick Craver, .sliders class moved to parent block. DL doesn't have class anymore. Sorry, forget to fix.

Comment: @Happy - The code in this answer will work for the current code in the question, give it a shot.

Comment: I would be happy if it is. Pay attention, I have moved .sliders class to top parent. The structure changed a bit, proposed code doesn't work.

Comment: @Happy - This code works against the html you posted, you can see for yourself, clicking the `text` link removes the `active` class from `Hide All`: http://jsfiddle.net/v7fs6/

Comment: I know where is the bug - I'm using an old version of jQuery, 1.2.6.

Comment: @Happy - When gzipped the difference is *very*, **very** small (and the client should be caching this anyway), you're best upgrading to the latest release, it has many bug fixes and enhancements as well.

Comment: @Nick Craver - thats true. The difference is the first load time. Trying to make a rocket like pages.

Comment: And even you can't know, if a client will use gzip.

Comment: @Nick Craver - the last question, where do you click, to insert nickname for quote, like "@Happy - "? I'm doing it manually

Comment: @Happy - 99.99999% of users will support gzip, this will not impact the load time of your clients.  You also have to consider that jQuery has made huge performance increases in 1.3 and 1.4, without upgrading you're missing out of those, probably yielding a **slower** experience for your users.

Comment: @Happy - no click, I type it :)

Comment: God! The next century on the street, where is the click option. Stackoverflow stuck in past :)

Answer (score 2):

Since `.sliders` and `.triggers` are siblings, you need to use `.closest()` to get `.sliders`, then traverse over to `.triggers`, and get its inner `a` element.

```
$(".sliders dt a").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.sliders').prev('.triggers').find("a.active").removeClass("active");
    return false;
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

Question changed, so now answer has changed:

```
$(".sliders dt a").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.sliders').find(".triggers a.active").removeClass("active");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I think this is wrong since, from the jQuery documentation, it finds ancestors, but .triggers is a sibling of .sliders

Comment: @hunter - Well, before the OP code changed, this would actually work since it was using `.closest()` to get the sibling, then using `.prev()` to get `.triggers()`. Moot point now that the question is different.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ECvGA/4/ - seens that jQuery 1.2.6. doesn't accept .closest()

Comment: Sorry, I had to write about, thought its not a big difference

Comment: @Happy - Yeah, `closest()` was introduced in version 1.3. jQuery 1.4.2 is definitely worth the upgrade.

Comment: @patrick - I have to accept Nick's, solution, he gave the first right answer. Voted for answer and your other two topics up. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How does parents() work? It walks up the DOM tree and collects all parents. Than it filters them by the selector specified.

Using jQuery 1.4+ more optimal is to use .closest(). It will work much faster if you have a lot of nodes on your page. Just a thought.

$(this).closest('.sliders').siblings('.triggers').find('a').removeClass(...);

Comment: This won't work, `.sliders` is not a sibling of `.triggers` it's a parent :)